# JRUN EATING 100%OF CPU

Tags: iis-6, coldfusion, virtualhost, jrun

We have a server with the following spec:

Intel Dual Core, 4GB.

We have MainEnable, Coldfusion, PHP, ASP and Mysql running on same server.
We have about 500+ emails account for Mail Enable.
We have about 91 domains.

I need to find out what is the limit of domains for a single computer and how much is too much so I can isolate the problem and find out what is causing JRUN to eat 100% of the CPU.

Comment: Coldfusion version? 6, 7, 8, 9? Standard, Enterprise Single instance, Enterprise Multiple instances?

Answer (score 2):

Answer would by typical: [FusionReactor](http://www.fusion-reactor.com/) is your friend.

Last time I had such problem with Jrun caused by endless loop in a buggy piece of code, FR saved me.

Comment: I need to know what FR is and figure out how to use it.

Comment: You need to click the link in the answer and find out. They have good website with all needed information. Please ask more specific information on ServerFault on any troubles using it.

Comment: @serji - maybe this should be a new question, but why FusionReactor instead of SeeFusion?

Answer (score 0):

MailEnable doesn't use Jrun.

Are you using a CF IMAP/POP webmail client connected to it?

Generically, I second Sergii's suggestion.  I've used FR several times to track down what pages were eating our server time.

Comment: Thanks In advance....
Yes we are using Imap/Pop and Webmail on the same server.
I need to know what FR is and figure out how to use it.

Comment: We don't have any CF IMAP /POP CONECTED TO IT.... Sorry I din't read the question well... I noticed that the request to any website built on mura increase the Jrun usage really high. It can be as low as 30 percent CPU Usage, but any time you do several request to mura pages, it consumes 90+ percent of the CPU.

Comment: FR referred to FusionReactor.  It's a CF monitoring and profiling application.  Mura is a CF CMS, and if hits to Mura are what is maxing out JRUN (which powers CF) then I'd contact the Mura community (http://www.getmura.com/).  I'm not sure why you are asking about MailEnable soecifically, as it does not seem to have anything to do with your problem.  You may want to edit your question to more closely reflect the actual situation.